# Are all of the features of C99 also in C++?

Tags: c++, c, c99, c89

[This page](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/newinc9x.htm) lists 53 features that were new in C99 (i.e they are in C99 but not C89). Are all of these features also in C++? Even C++98?

If not, which of the features are in C++ and which are not?

Comment: Is there one specifically you wish to know about, or do you intend to use all 53 features and making sure they'll all work?

Comment: You may wish to add the features into the question yourself, in case the link dies.

Comment: I'd say that most of the new core language features of C99 are NOT in C++. VLA are not in C++. Compound literals are not in C++. Flexible array member is not in C++. Syntax like `void foo(int a[const static 5])` is not in C++. `restrict` is not in C++. And so on. Cores of these language have diverged irrevocably. There's never been any intent to keep them in sync.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which parts of C89 are not included in C++98?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503880/which-parts-of-c89-are-not-included-in-c98)

Comment: This is broad, but someone could technically go through all 53 features and have a concrete answer, as AnT has already started doing, and it would be a very educational and constructive answer. I for one have never seen `a[const static 5]` before. Anyone could also go figure it out by themselves, but that's not the point. It's the same for many, many highly upvoted SO questions.

Comment: @MillieSmith -- but [don't-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) suggests that questions should be "reasonably scoped." Asking someone to go through a list of 53 features in an answer seems to strain credulity for "reasonably scoped."

Comment: Took 15 minutes to go through them. Sure, might have made some mistakes... But some C++ person could perhaps proof read.

Comment: *Too broad*? If anything, this question is *too precise*; changing just one small part of it yields a completely different answer, where-as this question is actually *better* when expressed in a more broad sense, as it'll elicit *more* information and *also* answer those other similar questions.

Comment: This question is specifically about features of C99. It is not a duplicate of "[Which parts of C89 are not included in C++98?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503880/which-parts-of-c89-are-not-included-in-c98)", which does not mention C99 at all.

Comment: In years down the road, this good question will lose precision as C++ evolves.  Consider titling the question to a specific version(s) of C++.  (maybe the last two as of 2017.)

Answer (score 28):

**The following C99 (ISO 9899:1999) features are fully supported by C++ (ISO 14882:2017):**
(though library headers will be `<cname>` rather than `<name.h>`:

> - wide character library support in `<wchar.h>` and `<wctype.h>` (originally
>     specified in ISO/IEC 9899:1990/Amd.1:1995)
> - type-generic math macros in `<tgmath.h>`
> - the long long int type and library functions
> - extended integer types
> - increased minimum translation limits
> - additional floating-point characteristics in `<float.h>`
> - remove implicit int
> - reliable integer division
> - universal character names (\u and \U)
> - extended identifiers
> - hexadecimal floating-point constants and %a and %A printf/scanf conversion
>     specifiers
> - // comments
> - specified width integer types and corresponding library functions in `<inttypes.h>` and `<stdint.h>`
> - remove implicit function declaration
> - preprocessor arithmetic done in intmax_t/uintmax_t
> - mixed declarations and statements
> - new block scopes for selection and iteration statements
> - integer constant type rules
> - integer promotion rules
> - the vscanf family of functions in `<stdio.h>` and `<wchar.h>`
> - additional math library functions in `<math.h>`
> - treatment of error conditions by math library functions (math_errhandling)
> - floating-point environment access in `<fenv.h>`
> - IEC 60559 (also known as IEC 559 or IEEE arithmetic) support
> - trailing comma allowed in enum declaration
> - %lf conversion specifier allowed in printf
> - inline functions
> - the snprintf family of functions in `<stdio.h>`
> - idempotent type qualifiers
> - empty macro arguments
> - additional predefined macro names
> - _Pragma preprocessing operator
> - standard pragmas
> - `__func__` predefined identifier
> - va_copy macro
> - additional strftime conversion specifiers
> - LIA compatibility annex
> - deprecate ungetc at the beginning of a binary file
> - remove deprecation of aliased array parameters
> - conversion of array to pointer not limited to lvalues
> - relaxed constraints on aggregate and union initialization
> - relaxed restrictions on portable header names
> - return without expression not permitted in function that returns a value (and vice
>     versa)
> - macros with a variable number of arguments

**The following C99 features have similar use in C++, but there are implementation differences and the languages are not code compatible:**

> - restricted character set support via digraphs and `<iso646.h>` (originally specified
>     in ISO/IEC 9899:1990/Amd.1:1995)
> - more precise aliasing rules via effective type
> - complex (and imaginary) support in `<complex.h>`
> - boolean type in `<stdbool.h>`
> - new structure type compatibility rules (tag compatibility)

**The following C99 features are not supported by C++:**

> - restricted pointers
> - variable length arrays
> - flexible array members
> - static and type qualifiers in parameter array declarators
> - compound literals
> - designated initializers

Comment: Since I'm hardly a C++ guru, I'm almost certain to have goofed up several of these. Hence community wiki. Please edit if you find any mistakes and move them to the correct category!

Comment: *macros with a variable number of arguments*, isn't that [variadic macros](macros with a variable number of arguments)?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes. These terms are taken from the C99 foreword. I just copy/pasted all the changes that were made in C99 from there.

Comment: I think what @NathanOliver is referring to is that, since C++11, C++ supports variadic macros. So, should "macros with a variable number of arguments" in a different category? Or is your answer specific to the older C++98?

Comment: @Lundin Sorry I messed up my link.  Since C++11 [variadic macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) are supported.

Comment: As written in the answer, and as per C++ tag policy, I'm assuming the current standard ISO 14882:2017. This is a community wiki, please feel free to fix any errors you spot.

Answer (score 3):

[Flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) are not part of any C++ standard (and the [dynarray](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2648.html) proposal was [not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20777801/841108) adapted in C++). And there are many other less used C99 features which are not in C++.