# C to C++ table inline definition

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have code in C that compiles and works correctly and I would like to use similar code in C++:

```
static const char* aTable[12] = {
    [4]="seems",
    [6]=" it  ",
[8]="works",};

int main(){
    printf("%s%s%s", aTable[4],aTable[6],aTable[8]); 
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I put it in a `.c` file and compiles with `gcc` it works. But, if I put it in a `.cpp` file and compile it with `g++`, I get the following errors:

```
test_cpp.cpp:5:3: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
test_cpp.cpp:5:4: error: type '<lambda>' with no linkage used to declare function 'void<lambda>::operator()() const' with linkage [-fpermissive] 
test_cpp.cpp: In lambda function: test_cpp.cpp:5:5: error: expected '{' before '=' token 
test_cpp.cpp: At global scope: test_cpp.cpp:5:5: warning: lambda expressions only available with
    -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default] 
test_cpp.cpp:5:6: error: no match for 'operator=' in '{} = "seems"' test_cpp.cpp:5:6: note: candidate is: test_cpp.cpp:5:4: note: <lambda()>&<lambda()>::operator=(const<lambda()>&) 
test_cpp.cpp:5:4: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char [6]' to 'const<lambda()>&' 
test_cpp.cpp:6:3: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
test_cpp.cpp:6:4: error: type '<lambda>' with no linkage used to declare function 'void<lambda>::operator()() const' with linkage [-fpermissive]
```

**Is there a way to express that I am not declaring a lambda function, just trying to fill a table?**

I would like to keep the following part :

```
[4]="seems",
[6]=" it  ",
[8]="works",
```

because it comes from an autogenerated file...

Comment: Just initialize explicitly all the values.

Comment: Remember that C and C++ are different languages? Even for historical version of compilers there was some incompatibilities, then for modern extensions of recent compilers problem is worst.

Comment: These are called "designated initializers" - helps doing google searches. Though I didn't find anything good.

Comment: There is no comparable syntax, you just have to put them in the correct order and fill in the blanks.

Comment: Or compile *that* file with a modern C compiler and link.

Comment: its quite rare that both the c and c++ tags are ontopic. On top of that this nicely demonstrates that c++, in contrast to common misbelieve, is not a superset of c. What a nice question :)

Comment: It looks like this WILL be allowed in C++20....

Comment: @aschepler I thought the C++20 proposal was only for `.name = value`, not `[index] = value`.

Comment: @hvd Oops yes, looks like you're right.

Comment: Doesn't GCC support designated initialisers as *extension*? Would require to compile with one of the `-std=gnuXYZ` modes, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can mix C and C++ code easily.

You should keep the C code to be compiled with C compiler (gcc), rest of the code can be C++ and be compiled with C++ compiler (g++). then link all object (.o) files together.

like this:

file name: **a.c**

```
const char* aTable[12] = {
    [4]="seems",
    [6]=" it  ",
[8]="works",};
```

file name: **b.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>
extern "C" const char* aTable[12];   
int main(){
    printf("%s%s%s", aTable[4],aTable[6],aTable[8]); 
    return 0;
}
```

Now compile:

```
gcc -c a.c -o a.o
g++ -c b.cpp -o b.o
g++ b.o a.o -o all.out
```

Now run the executable (all.out) and you'll see that everything will work.

Just note that for functions you'll need to add `extern "C"` before the declaration in the cpp file.

Comment: That should be `extern "C" const char* aTable[12];` too: IIRC at least one compiler performs name mangling otherwise.

Comment: @hvd In g++\gcc (both was tagged in the question) it works without the `extern "C"`, And I tried to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Bonus: As the table is generated, it certainly is a file of its own anyway

Comment: @SHR It is better to keep it as correct as possible while remaining simple.

Comment: Ok, I've added the `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 16):

There's no way to do this. C++ never adopted this particular C syntax.

In your case, since the table is auto-generated, I would just put it in a C file. As long as it's not marked `static`, it can be accessed from C++ code without problems.

Answer (score 13):

`[4]=` is a *designated initializer*, one of the C features not supported by C++.

Here is a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524553/are-all-of-the-features-of-c99-also-in-c/47526708#47526708) that tries to list which C99 features that are supported by C++17. Scroll down to the bottom to see which ones that are not supported.

It is important to realize that C++ is by no means a superset of C.

Comment: C and C++ are two languages separated by a common syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Designated initialisers not being supported by C++ already mentioned – if you insist on C++, you could write a wrapper class with a constructor instead:

```
class Table
{
    std::array<char const*, 12> data;
public:
    Table()
    {
        data[4] = "seems";
        data[6] = " it  ";
        data[8] = "works";
    }
    char const* operator[](unsigned int index) const
    {
        return data[index];
    }
} aTable;
```

Did not test the code, so if you find a bug, feel free to fix it yourself...

Answer (score 2):

As said above, this type of initialization is not supported in C++, but you could use lambda function to initialize `static array<const char*, 12>` like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdio>

static const std::array<const char*, 6> aTable = []() {
    std::array<const char*, 6> table;
    table[0] = "Hello";
    table[3] = ", ";
    table[5] = "world!";
    return std::move(table);
}();

int main() {
    printf("%s%s%s\n", aTable[0], aTable[3], aTable[5]);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b79e084124beedc)</kbd>

Notable, that compiler will do [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) here, and the initialization will be performed in-place. This is assembly generated by g++-5.4.0:

```
<_GLOBAL__sub_I_main>:
movq   $0x40064c,0x200bc5(%rip)        # 601060 <_ZL6aTable>
movq   $0x400652,0x200bd2(%rip)        # 601078 <_ZL6aTable+0x18>
movq   $0x400655,0x200bd7(%rip)        # 601088 <_ZL6aTable+0x28>
retq
```