# Does reading to another variant member of a union that has the same type as the active variant cause UB?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

```cpp
union A{
  int a;
  int b;
};
int main(){
  A u = {.a = 0};
  int r = u.b; // #1 Is this UB?
}
```

[class.union] says

> In a union, a non-static data member is active if its name refers to an object whose lifetime has begun and has not ended ([basic.life]).
> At most one of the non-static data members of an object of union type can be active at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time.

In this example, only `A::a` is active, then [basic.life] p7 says

> The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> > - the glvalue is used to access the object, or

`#1` tries to access the object whose lifetime has not begun. Does this access cause UB, if it is, is this requirement too restrictive?

BTW, Does the C standard impose the same requirement in this example? Or, Does C have a looser requirement in this case?

#### Update

In [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf), I find a note, which says

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the
> object the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new
> type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called type punning). This might be a non-value representation.

This means it is permitted in C. However, https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.iso

> Subclause [diff.iso] lists the differences between C++ and ISO C, in addition to those listed above, by the chapters of this document.

does not point out the difference.

Comment: [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) has this note: "If two union members are standard-layout types, it's well-defined to examine their common subsequence on any compiler." Though I didnt bother to check where to find the corresponding section in the standard

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No, they are not the same thing. The formal wording is [[class.mem.general] p26](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-26), The precondition is such two variants should be struct type. Moreover, the concept "common initial sequence" is in terms of "standard-layout struct".

Comment: ok. Seems like cppref is not quite accurate then, or the note is supposed to refer to the previous section which is about uninon members of class type

Comment: C allows type punning through a union, so I suspect it's legal C code.  AFAIK this is UB per the standard but I've not seen a C++ compiler do the wrong thing when working with fundamental types.  This gets more muddled in C++20 since `int` is an implicit lifetime type meaning `b` should be alive as storage exists for it.

Comment: @NathanOliver See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1, you will notice how the lifetime of a variant of a union will begin(emphasized "only" in the quote).

Comment: [diff.iso] is informative, not normative, so omission of a difference between C and C++ is presumptively an oversight, not an authoritative statement. Even if it were normative, it would be controlling only for C++ and would have no authority of the C standard.

Comment: I think this is mostly correct still https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning, so maybe a duplicate.

Comment: Btw the annex supposedly containing all differences between C and C++ is _laughable_. At some point I tried to compile a [list of C99-unique features also present in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524553/are-all-of-the-features-of-c99-also-in-c/47526708#47526708) and that list alone has more bullets with various language quirks than the C++ annex. Why ISO C++ contains laughable, terribly outdated annexes is a different topic however...

Comment: Ok since you have essentially answered the question yourself, I'll go ahead and close as dupe unless someone has new info as per the C23 C++23 releases...? Normative text in C++ is the quoted "At most one of the non-static data members of an object of union type can be active at any time", normative text in C is 6.5.2.3 "A postfix expression followed by the . operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member" (the quoted foot note points at this text). And [diff.iso] is to be dismissed entirely.

Comment: @NathanOliver fwiw the Qt project did have a bug where they had a union containing a pointer and a `uintptr_t`. They toggled the lower bit of the `uintptr_t` then called a method through the pointer. On some platforms, the method would be called with `this` keeping it old value.

Comment: At least Clang considers your code UB, and disallows it in constant expressions: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TrWvMf1Ph

Comment: @Fedor However, GCC and MSVC do not render any error, as indicated https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q41rMrxbE, which means there is some room of debate here.

Comment: @xmh0511, GCC and MSVC render this error as well: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/We4zYzdaa

Comment: Although limited to struct members of a union whilst OPs example are fundamental types, [\[class.mem.general\]/25](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general#25) arguably adds some confusion to this topic with its glvalue-allowed read with the effect _"as if the corresponding member [...] were nominated"_.

Comment: @dfrib Yep, [class.mem.general]/25 only applies to two variants that are of struct types, see https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/135

Answer (score 5):

I think in C++ this is undefined behavior per the first standard quotation in the question itself: there is no exception there for the case of same types of data members.

And major compilers seem to agree with this reading, disallowing such code in constant expressions:

```
union A{
  int a;
  int b;
};

constexpr int f() {
  A u = {.a = 0};
  return u.b;
}

constexpr int x = f();
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/We4zYzdaa

Clang's error:

```
read of member 'b' of union with active member 'a' is not allowed in a constant expression
```

GCC's error:

```
accessing 'A::b' member instead of initialized 'A::a' member in constant expression
```

MSVC's error:

```
failure was caused by accessing a non-active member of a union
```

Comment: Interestingly, all compilers also reject the very similar but explicitly allowed example of [\[class.mem.general\]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general#25). [DEMO](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/von1seb4q).

Comment: @dfrib the common initial sequence rule is not allowed in a constant expression context b/c it [does not change the active member](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.10)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That would explain it, thanks. Would the wording of class.mem.general, "[...] **the behavior is as if** the corresponding member of T1 were nominated." need some rewriting or clarification, or is it clear from somewhere that "as if" does not mean a special case that excludes that of expr.const/5.10?

Answer (score 3):

> Does reading to another variant member of a union that has the same type as the active variant cause UB?

The rule is clear. One member is active. Reading inactive is UB.

> Does this access cause UB

Yes.

> , if it is, is this requirement too restrictive?

No idea. Subjective: Not for me. It is fine. I see no value in having two members of the same type in a union and then accessing them one or the other.

> Does the C standard impose the same requirement in this example?

No. One of examples that C and C++ are different.

> Does C have a looser requirement in this case?

Yes. In C, you can read any member from a union you want to. The requirement is that the assessed value will not be a trap representation.

Related: [Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning)